# Problem with storage and iPad glitches

Tags: storage

Recently my iPad (running on 0.7.0)has been glitching a lot lately.It says there is a message that I haven't read even though there isn't any.I have also bought 200GB storage to have space and update apps but when I try it says I don't have any space and I only have one app that I need to update.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Space you bought is iCloud space? That space is not used for your local apps, local music, local photos etc. The iCloud space is just for everything stored online, e.g. your mail, your online photos, or data of apps that sync across devices. If you have glitches in the usability of your device, you should reinstall the Software. Make sure you back up everything you need, e.g. your photos or contacts, since everything will be overwritten during this process. Then make sure you have the latest version of iTunes installed on your computer, if you have a Windows Machine, search for "Apple Software Update" in your Applications, or download the latest version of iTunes from the Apple Homepage https://apple.com/itunes. On a Mac you'd just have to check "Software Update" (in the Apple menu at the top left) until OS X 10.6., or the App Store (from OS X 10.7). Then connect your device, open it in itunes and click "Restore Firmware". It will do a complete software update, follow the onscreen instructions, and everything should be fine afterwards.